# typescript (ionic2) email validation using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, ionic2, email-validation

I am having trouble with using Typescript to validate if an email address is valid or invalid using regular expression this is what I have.
I got a runtime error "cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

```
   public signup(email){
    var reg = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!lsu.edu)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
    if (reg.test(email.value) == false) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Error ',
      subTitle: 'Invalid email.',
      buttons:['Try Again']
    });
    alert.present();
    return false;
  }
 }
```

full code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { BackandService } from '@backand/angular2-sdk'
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';




@Component({
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
  selector: 'page-signup',
 })

export class SignupPage {

  email:string = '';
  firstName:string = '';
  lastName:string = '';
  signUpPassword: string = '';
  confirmPassword: string = '';
  bloodType: Object = {};



  constructor(private backand: BackandService, private alertCtrl: 
 AlertController) {

  }


  public signUp(email) {

  if(this.email == '' || this.firstName == '' ||  this.lastName == '' ||  this.signUpPassword == '' ||  this.confirmPassword == ''){
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Error ',
    subTitle: 'Must fill in all fields.',
    buttons:['Try Again']
  });
  alert.present();
}


  if(this.signUpPassword != this.confirmPassword){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Error ',
      subTitle: 'Passwords must match.',
      buttons:['Try Again']
    });
    alert.present();
    }

  if(this.signUpPassword.length < 6 && this.confirmPassword.length < 6){
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Error ',
      subTitle: 'Password must be 6 characters.',
      buttons:['Try Again']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

 var reg = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!lsu.edu)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
  if (reg.test(email.value) == false) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Error ',
      subTitle: 'Invalid email.',
      buttons:['Try Again']
    });
    alert.present();
    return false;
 }


this.backand.signup(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.signUpPassword, this.confirmPassword, this.bloodType)
.then((res: any) =>
  {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    subTitle: 'Thank you for signing up.',
    buttons:['Login']
  });
  alert.present();
    this.email = this.signUpPassword = this.confirmPassword = this.firstName = this.lastName = this.bloodType = '';
  }
);
  }
}
```

Comment: What trouble did you have?

Comment: I got a runtime error "cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: This means your `email` is undefined. The error is irrelevant to regex. The problem is about the code calling `signup()`.

Comment: Your regex matches `---@` that is not a valid email address

Comment: It's complaining that the `email` parameter is `undefined` (so you can't call `email.value`). Explain how and where you call the function.

Comment: You're having a property `this.email` and a parameter `email`, the property is a string, which would mean that you don't need to call `.value` if the parameter is as well. What happens if you replace all `email` with `this.email` and don't call `.value`?

Comment: Thank you that works, but I also think I have the incorrect regex. Do you know what is the correct regex for ---> @lsu.edu ?

Answer (score 0):

**validation email type script** &&
**validation mot de passe type script**

```html
validateData(field: any) {
    const validateEmail = (email: any) => {
      return String(email)
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
          /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        );
    };
    switch (field) {
      case 'userName':
        if (this.user.userName == '') {
          this.errorMessages.userName = "l'adresse email ne peut pas être vide";
        } else if (! validateEmail(this.user.userName)) {
          this.errorMessages.userName = 'Adresse email non valide';
        } else this.errorMessages.userName = '';
        break;
      case 'nom':
        if (this.user.nom == '')
          this.errorMessages.nom = 'le prénom ne peut pas être vide';
        else this.errorMessages.nom = '';
        break;
      case 'prenom':
        if (this.user.prenom == '')
          this.errorMessages.prenom = 'le nom ne peut pas être vide';
        else this.errorMessages.prenom = '';
        break;
      case 'userName':
        if (this.user.userName == '')
          this.errorMessages.userName =
            "le nom d'utilisateur ne peut pas être vide";
        else this.errorMessages.userName = '';
        break;

      case 'password2':
        if (this.password2 == '')
          this.errorMessages.password2 =
            'confirmation mot de passe ne peut pas être vide';
        else this.errorMessages.password2 = '';
        break;

      case 'password':
        if (this.user.password == '')
          this.errorMessages.password = 'le mot de passe ne peut pas être vide';
        else if (!this.user.password.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
          this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum un chiffre';
        } else if (!this.user.password.match(/[a-z]/g)) {
          this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum une lettre minuscule';
        } else if (!this.user.password.match(/[A-Z]/g)) {
          this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum une lettre majuscule';
        } else if (!(this.user.password.length >= 10)) {
          this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum 10 caractères';
        } else this.errorMessages.password = '';
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```